# Flask: Set session cookie based on domain name

Tags: python, flask, session-variables, session-cookies

I'm new to flask and python and am working on a project where we have a web site that can be reached via two different domains. The code base is the same, but the domains are branded differently. I'll need to load a domain-specific stylesheet and in a couple of template blocks I'll need to use some conditionals to only display some content if I'm on a certain domain.

I'd think the best way to do this is to create a session variable based on the domain (other suggestions welcome). It gets set when a visitor comes in on one of the domains, and then I can use conditionals to load the appropriate stylesheet/block of code.

I'm having trouble getting this working though. Right now in my app.py file, I have a "client" session variable that is set based on url parameters that is being called before each request:

```
@app.before_request
def set_client_session():
    if 'client' in request.args:
        session['client'] = request.args['client']
```

How can I set it using the domain instead of URL params, and how can I check its value in a template so that I can conditionally load a stylesheet/block of code?

Full app.py file:

```
import os
import json
from flask import Flask, session, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

# Generate a secret random key for the session
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

@app.before_request
def set_client_session():
    if 'client' in request.args:
        session['client'] = request.args['client']

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/edc')
def abc():
    return render_template('pages/abc.html')

@app.route('/success')
def success():
    return render_template('success.html')

@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('pages/contact.html')

@app.route('/privacy')
def privacy():
    return render_template('pages/privacy.html')

@app.route('/license')
def license():
    return render_template('pages/license.html')

@app.route('/install')
def dcm_download():
    return render_template('pages/install.html')

@app.route('/uninstall')
def uninstall():
    return render_template('pages/uninstall.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the domain/hostname with `request.headers['Host']` and then set it to session.

```
@app.before_request
def set_domain_session():
    session['domain'] = request.headers['Host']
```

Also, `request.url_root` will give you the domain and the protocol in case you need it. (e.g. `http://domain.com/`)

Then in the jinja2 templates, you can access the session variable and check for the domain.

```
{% if session.domain == 'domain1.com' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/domain1.css') }}">
{% else %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/domain2.css') }}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The domain is being set correctly, but the conditionals are not. I'm working on a local dev server so right now the domain is localhost:5000. When I check if the value of session.domain == 'localhost:5000', it returns false. If I only check whether there is a session.domain, it returns true. When I output {{session.domain}}, it is definitely localhost:5000, so for some reason checking if session.domain == 'localhost:5000' isn't working.

Comment: Very weird. I just tested it myself to be sure and it's working perfectly. The `{{ session.domain == 'localhost:5000' }}` equality check is returning True on my end. It's silly but try doing `{{ 'a' == 'a' }}` and see if it returns True or not